Is this a misstatement of Euclid in Halmos' Naive Set Theory book?
I was reading Halmos’ Naive Set Theory. On page 1, he writes,

One thing that the development will not include is a definition of
sets. The situation is analogous to the familiar axiomatic approach to
elementary geometry. That approach does not offer a definition of
points and lines; instead it describes what it is that one can do with
those objects.

What can Halmos mean here? Euclid defines point and line as Definitions 1 and 2 of Book 1.
When Halmos writes “the familiar axiomatic approach to elementary geometry” I assumed that he was referring to Euclid. Is he referring to some other type of post-Euclidean geometry?
I don’t think a mathematician of Halmos’ stature would not know that Euclid defines point and line.
The same idea is repeated in this video and “set” and “element” are said to be “common notions” as in Euclid implying that in Euclid point and line are common notions:

In set theory “set” and “element” are usually considered to be
undefined terms kind of like in geometry the points and lines are
considered undefined terms. They are just common notions that we agree
upon the meaning but we don’t actually say “definition.”


What do you think Halmos meant?


"I assumed that he was referring to Euclid." What justification do you have for that assumption?

Even assuming that Euclid's 'definitions' are genuine, which is doubtful, they are mathematically useless and are not, in fact, used in his proofs. Nor do they define what is intended, empty set is also "that which has no part" and any curve is "breadthless length". Their role is informal, the same as pointing to what Halmos calls "the ordinary, human, intuitive (and frequently erroneous) understanding of what sets are."

@Conifold So, you are saying that because Euclid does not use his definition of point explicitly in any of his proofs the Definition 1 of Book 1 is superfluous.
I don't agree with this view.
Euclid does use this definition. The definition of point is at the foundation of Euclid's geometry.

@Conifold First, Euclid uses Definition 1 to define a line. Without his definition of point his definition of line will not make sense.
Euclid uses his definition of point in his Postulate 1: "To draw a straight line from any point to any point."
The definition of point as position without extension is used throughout the book. The center of a circle is a point that only has position and no extension.
I believe that it is unfair to Euclid to dismiss his definition of point as superfluous.

First, Euclid does not use them in those and other places, they are simply mentioned there. And we know because those mentions can be removed without changing the logic of proofs. Second, if he did have to use them his proofs would be invalid because the theorems are false for curved triangles, etc. And third, those mentions are late insertions for didactic purposes, and it is to Euclid's credit as a sharp mathematical mind that he kept such superfluous insertions out of his text.

No error at all.
Euclid's definitions:

Definition 1. A point is that which has no part.


Definition 2. A line is breadthless length,

are probably later interpolations aimed at clarify the primitive notions; they and not proper definitions because we do not know what "part" is and what "breadthless length" is.
See Lucio Russo, The Definitions of Fundamental Geometric Entities Contained in Book I of Euclid's Elements (AHES, 1998):

Definitions like these are today considered useless and their inclusion in the Elements is usually seen as a serious flaw in the Elements. A few authors, on the other hand, have raised doubts of a generic nature on their authenticity.


The thesis is sustained that the definitions of fundamental geometric entities which open Euclid’s Elements actually are excerpts from the Definitions by Heron of Alexandria, interpolated in late antiquity into Euclid’s treatise.

Here is Heron's text:

A point is that which has no parts or an extremity without extension or the extremity of a line.

Halmos is reflecting modern point of view regarding axiomatic; see David Hilbert, The Foundations of Geometry (1899):

Let us consider three distinct systems of things. The things composing the first system, we will call points [...]; those of the second, we will call straight lines [...] We think of these points, straight lines, and planes as having certain mutual relations, which we indicate by means of such words as “are situated,” “between,” “parallel,” “congruent,” “continuous,” etc. The complete and exact description of these relations
follows as a consequence of the axioms of geometry.

In conclusion: what is a point? A point is an object that satisfies the relevant axioms of geometry.
The same regarding set.

I don't think "elucidate" is the right word here. Euclid is not elucidating on the concept of point, he is defining it. You may say that this is not a good definition, but this does not make it an elucidation. If "elucidate" has a technical meaning in mathematics, I'm not aware of that. If I may be allowed to elucidate :) on Definition 1, I think Euclid simply says that "a point is position without extension." I think this is a beautiful definition. Yes, "position" and "extension" are taken as primitives, but I think this is allowed.Thanks for the link to set definition question. Great answers

Halmos does not mention Euclid by name. Axiomatic approach to geometry indeed does not use these "definitions", neither Euclid really does.
Since original text of Euclid has not been preserved (only much later copies), many historians speculate that these "definitions" were added by later commentators. (For example Lucio Russo in his papers
and book "Forgotten revolution").

"Axiomatic approach to geometry..." So, like Halmos, you refer to post-Euclidean axiomatic geometry developed by Hilbert when you say axiomatic geometry. Mauro Allegranza's answer made this clear for me. Halmos is not referring to Euclid. But I don't think the authorship of Euclid's book is relevant to my question. We are only interested if point and line are defined in the book traditionally known as Euclid's elements. And they are. But Halmos is not referring to that book anyway :) Looks very interesting but I could not access Russo's book and I could not find a pdf of it.

@zeynel: You may try to find his paper: Lucio Russo, The Definitions of Fundamental Geometric Entities Contained in Book I of Euclid's Elements, Archive for History of Exact Sciences 52 (3):195-219 (1998). The main point is that Euclid never uses these "definitions".

Euclid uses his definition of a point to define a line and in his postulate 1. The center of a  circle is a point that has position but no extension as defined by definition 1. Even if Euclid does not use his definition of point explicitly in a proof, point is a fundamental part of the logical development of his geometry.
